# Boto3 DynamoDb scan with contains filter not returning any results

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to use a simple `contains` filter with boto3 DynamoDb table resource. My code is as follows:

```
search = "SomeProductText"
response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression='contains(product_text, :pt )',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':pt': {'S': search}
    }
)
print(response['Items'])

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(
        ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'],
        FilterExpression='contains(product_text, :pt )',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':pt': {'S': search}
        }
    )
    print(response['Items'])
```

This prints out only empty lists and I'm not getting any results. When I go to the dynamodb console and try this same scan there I get many results where the `product_text` contains "SomeProductText" as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: does the first print have any items?

Comment: We need to see your table resource and your client - please post a complete code snippet and the resulting output of running the entire code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't provide the full code snippet I'll take an educated guess to the issue. The fact you call your client `table` leads me to believe you're using the `Resource` client which takes native JSON not DynamoDB-JSON:.

```
search = "SomeProductText"
response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression='contains(product_text, :pt )',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':pt': search
    }
)
print(response['Items'])

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(
        ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'],
        FilterExpression='contains(product_text, :pt )',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':pt': search
        }
    )
    print(response['Items'])
```

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem in my case.